# How to remove the null pointer exception in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a file with values like:

a,9,1

b,2,4

c,2,4

till *,2,0
and this is my code:

```
    public static final String letterFileLoc = "filelocation";
    public static Map<Character, Integer> letterValueMap;
    public static Map<Character, Integer> letterCountMap;
    public static void constructLetterMaps() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File pointvals = new File(letterFileLoc);
    Scanner pts = new Scanner(pointvals);
    while (pts.hasNext()){
        String [] parts = pts.next().split(",");
        char alpha = (parts[0]).charAt(0);
        int counts = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int values = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        letterValueMap.put(alpha, values);
        letterCountMap.put(alpha, counts);
      }
```

and I keep getting a null pointer expception when I'm putting the values. I don't understand why. Could someone please explain?

Comment: You never initialize  `letterValueMap` and `letterCountMap`?!

Comment: just edited my description

Comment: as @Jens said: you just declared the `Map`s, but never initialized them. Next time, please paste the concrete error message given by the compiler with your code.

Comment: Static is not your friend, beware

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `letterValueMap` and `letterCountMap` like this:

```
letterValueMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
letterCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Put that code anywhere in your class where it will be run before the two `Map`s are used.

You can also initialize them when they declared, like this:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> letterValueMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
public static Map<Character, Integer> letterCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
 public static Map<Character, Integer> letterValueMap;
 public static Map<Character, Integer> letterCountMap;
```

... but you have not initialised them. You need to call the constructors somewhere; e.g.:

```
 static{
   letterValueMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
   letterCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
 }
```